# $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\log(n)}\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{\cos (\sin (2 \pi \log (k)))}{k}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

What tools would you gladly recommend me for computing *precisely* the limit below? Maybe a starting point?
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\log(n)}\sum _{k=1}^n \frac{\cos (\sin (2 \pi  \log (k)))}{k}$$

Comment: @downvoters, I said "tools", not solutions.

Comment: Not even twenty seconds in, and already a downvote... I'm impressed...

Comment: I suspect the limit is $\;J_0(1) \approx 0.7651976865579665514497\;$ but I don't have a proof of that.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe it is possible to express that limit in any familiar way?

Comment: @WilliamStagner a hand-waving argument is convert the sum to an integral over $\log(k)$. Since $\sin(x)$ is periodic, ultimately the limit becomes some sort of average $\cos(\sin(2\pi x))$.

Comment: @Winther It turns out it is not that hard to bound the difference between the sum and the integral. From that, one can show the limit is  $J_0(1)$ (see my answer).

Comment: @achillehui Yes I got the same answer myself (hand-waving, not rigorous), but the numerics seemed to give a different conclusion. Math 1 - Computer 0.

Comment: @Chris'ssis: You're Romanian too !?

Comment: @Lucian Yeap. A self-educated one, not a product in any way of the educational system from my country. Are you Romanian?

Comment: @Chris'ssis: Yep. Do you know many non-Romanians called Lucian ? ;-)

Comment: @Lucian Nice to meet you. :-) Are you a student, a professor?

Comment: @Chris'ssis: Neither, nor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \frac{\cos(\sin(2\pi x))}{x}$, we have

$$f'(x) = - \frac{2\pi\cos(2\pi x)\sin(\sin(2\pi x)) + \cos(\sin(2\pi x))}{x^2}
\implies |f'(x)| \le \frac{2\pi + 1}{x^2}
$$
By MVT, for any $x \in (k,k+1]$, we can find a $\xi \in (0,1)$ such that

$$|f(x) - f(k)| = |f'(k + \xi(x-k))|(x-k) \le \frac{2\pi+1}{k^2}$$

This implies

$$\left| \int_k^{k+1} f(x) dx - f(k)\right| \le \frac{2\pi+1}{k^2}$$

As a result,

$$|\sum_{k=1}^n f(k) - \int_1^n f(x) dx| 
\le |f(n)| + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \left|f(k) - \int_k^{k+1} f(x)dx\right|\\
\le 1 + (2\pi + 1)\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}
= 1 + \frac{(2\pi + 1)\pi^2}{6} < \infty$$

As a result,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\log n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}f(k) 
= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{\log n}\int_1^n f(x) dx
= \lim_{L\to\infty}\frac{1}{L}\int_0^L f(e^t) de^t\\
= \lim_{L\to\infty}\frac{1}{L}\int_0^L \cos(\sin(2\pi t)) dt
$$
Since the integrand is periodic with period $1$, the limit at the right exists
and equal to

$$\begin{align}
 & \int_0^1\cos(\sin(2\pi t))dt = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(\sin(t)) dt = J_0(1)\\ 
\approx & 0.765197686557966551449717526102663220909274289755325
\end{align}
$$
where 
$J_0(x)$ 
is the [Bessel function of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel_functions_of_the_first_kind:_J.CE.B1).

Answer (score 2):

I would start with this:

$$0\leq \left|\frac{1}{\log(n)}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{\cos(\sin(2\pi\log(k)))}{k}\right|\leq \frac{1}{\log{n}}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k}$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the standard estimate for the harmonic numbers,
$$
\left| \frac{1}{\log n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\cos(\sin(2\pi \log(k)))}{k}\right| \leq \frac{1}{\log n} \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k} = \frac{1}{\log n}(\log(n) + \gamma + O(1/n)).
$$
So in the limit,
$$
\left| \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{\log n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\cos(\sin(2\pi \log(k)))}{k} \right| \leq 1.
$$
This is a pretty elementary bound, so you were probably already aware of it, but hopefully it helps.